# When does Socket.Receive return the data?

Tags: c#, sockets

Beginner Question again: Kind of a follow up to a question I asked not long ago.

I am trying to understand this synchronous socket tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3.aspx, particularly one single line in the code below.

**QUESTION:** 
I want to make sure I am understanding the program flow right . **When** does handler.Receive(bytes) return? Does it return and store the number of bytes received in **int bytesRec**when it "overflows" and has received more than 1024bytes? **And if that is so**, and this might sound silly, what happens if MORE bytes arrive as it is storing the 1024 bytes in the **data**variable and not listening for more bytes that might be arriving at that time? Or should I not worry about it and let .net take care of that?

```
Socket handler = listener.Accept();
data = null;

// An incoming connection needs to be processed.
while (true) {
    bytes = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
    // My question is WHEN does the following line
    // get to be executed
    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec);
    if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> When does handler.Receive(bytes) return?

Documentation:

> If no data is available for reading, the Receive method will block
>   until data is available, unless a time-out value was set by using
>   Socket.ReceiveTimeout. If the time-out value was exceeded, the Receive
>   call will throw a SocketException. If you are in non-blocking mode,
>   and there is no data available in the in the protocol stack buffer,
>   the Receive method will complete immediately and throw a
>   SocketException. You can use the Available property to determine if
>   data is available for reading. When Available is non-zero, retry the
>   receive operation.

---

> Does it return and store the number of bytes received in int
>   bytesRec when it "overflows" and has received more than 1024 bytes?

No, it always returns the number of bytes that have been read. If it didn't, how could you know what part of `bytes` contains meaningful data and what part of it has remained unused?

It is **very important** to understand how sockets typically work: bytes may be arriving in packets, but as far as the receiver is concerned *each byte should be considered independently*. This means that there is no guarantee that you will get the bytes in the chunks the sender sent them, and of course there is no guarantee that there is enough data to fill up your buffer.

If you only want to process incoming data in 1024-byte chunks, it is your own responsibility to keep calling `Receive` until it has released 1024 bytes in total to you.

> And if that is so, and this might sound silly, what happens if MORE
>   bytes arrive as it is storing the 1024 bytes in the variable and
>   not listening for more bytes that might be arriving at that time?

Let's reiterate that `Receive` will not store 1024 bytes in the buffer because that's the buffer's size. It will store **up to** 1024 bytes.

If there is more data buffered internally by the network stack than your buffer can hold then 1024 bytes will be given back to you and the rest will stay in the network stack's buffers until you call `Receive` again. If `Receive` has begun copying data to your buffer and at that moment more data is received from the network then most likely what's going to happen is that these will have to wait for the next `Receive` call.

After all, at no point did anyone provide a guarantee that `Receive` would give you *all* the data it can (although of course that is desirable and it is what happens most of the time).

Comment: You can think of Receive much like reading from a file.  If there is enough bytes of data still in the file (in this case network stack), it will return up to your buffer's size off the top, otherwise it will return the rest of the data (which can be less than your buffer size).

Comment: @shellster: Kind of. But that description glosses over the very important fact that the network stack may decide to hand you data in whatever chunks it *chooses* to. There is no guarantee.

Comment: @Jon thanks for a superb answer. When you say " the network stack may decide to hand you data in whatever chunks it chooses to" does it mean that my client may send "Sorry darling, I'm not single but married" but my server may receive " but married" before  "sorry darling"? The microsoft code above does no such error checking...wouldnt tcp/ip take care of that so i receive data in the right order

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it: No, because of the [guarantees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Data_transfer) that TCP provides (assuming you are using TCP sockets). But it could give you all the data in one go, or a single letter with each `Receive` call, or anything in between. *Most of the time* it will give it back in chunks just as the sender sent it, but you can't count on that. See also another answer of mine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5641988/50079).